# finding audio driver

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, audio, sound-card, device-manager

I have a soundcard in my new PC at work that does not have the right driver installed, and I'm not sure what the manufacturer is. (it's a generic PC running Windows XP)

Is there a way to figure out what device it is w/o having to open the thing up or pester my IT department?

When I look at it in Device Manager it says `IDT High Definition Audio CODEC` and when I look around in the Properties dialog boxes there's a Device Instance ID of

```
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_111D&DEV_76C1&SUBSYS_12974001&REV_1001\4&3612FC2B&0&0001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to PC Drivers HeadQuarters your sound-card is [IDT HIGH DEFINITION AUDIO CODEC MEDION REALTEK](http://www.drivershq.com/driver-update/audio-and-sound/idt/idt-high-definition-audio-codec/medion-realtek-sound-driver/241035/).

You might try downloading the XP executable installation from the Realtek site at [Drivers & Utilities](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=24&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false).

Answer (score 0):

Pester your IT department. If it's at work and it's a work computer, it's what thet get paid for.

As for how to track down what the device actually is: Usually [Everest](http://www.lavalys.com/support/downloads) is pretty good at giving you a vendor name and model number of individual hardware components.

Answer (score 0):

Use [HWiNFO32](http://www.hwinfo.com/download32.html) it displays all your devices.  You might need to uninstall the driver and then run it.